# How to not allow duplicate words?

Tags: regex

I need a Regex expression which won't accept repeated words (a-z). 
For example:

```
cat dog mouse
```

Would be accepted

```
cat dog cat
```

Would not be accepted

Comment: While this may be possible with a regular expression, it will be complicated. Would it be acceptable to do something simpler like using a hash lookup to spot duplicates? Also, this question being about programming it might get more attention on Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like

```
(\w+)(?!.*?\1)
```

Or, if you don't want "cat" matches "caterpillar" :

```
(\b\w+\b)(?!.*?\b\1\b)
```